# how to use react routing to switch between pages

Tags: reactjs, routes

i am currently building a shopping website . i finished the homepage and i have to make routing for other pages
i have 3 main files: App.js, Menuitem.js (which is to execute props), and Homepage.js (which also is used to apply executing props from sections array which includes titles and background images and sections paths)

this is the App js

```
import React from "react";
import Homepage from './Homepage'
import "./styles.css";
import './Homepage.css'
import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
const Hatspage=function() {
  return(
    <div>
      <h1>
        Hats page
      </h1>
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/'component={Homepage}/>
          <Route   path='/hats'component={Hatspage}/>
        </Switch>
     </div>        


  );
}
export default  App
```

Menuitem.js

```
    import React from 'react'
import {WithRouter} from 'react'


const Menuitem= function(props){
    return(
        <div className='card' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.imageUrl})` }} >
            <div className='text-frame'> 
                 <h1 className='title'>{props.title}</h1>
                <p className='subtitle'>shop now</p>
            </div>
         </div>
    
    )
}

export default Menuitem
```

Homepage.js

```
import React from "react";
import sections from './directory-components';
import Menuitem from "./menu-item-components";
const arrayOne=[sections.slice(0,3)]
const arrayTwo=[sections.slice(3,)]
function extract(item){
  return(
    <Menuitem 
    title={item.title}  imageUrl={item.imageUrl}/>
  )
}
function Homepage(){
    return(
    <div className='directory-menu'>
            <div className='content'>
                {sections.slice(0,3).map(extract) }
            </div>
            <div className='second'>
               {sections.slice(3,).map(extract) }
            </div>
    </div>
    )
}
export default Homepage
```

so i need for example when i click on hats picture i switch to hats page . how to do that
image attached
Thanks in advance

[reactjs routing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyMBV.jpg)

Comment: Seems that your MenuItem component should use the Link component from react router, can you post the code for your MenuItem component please?

Comment: i have already sent menuitem.js code

Comment: I think you're missing the menu item code, since you're just posting the extract function which only calls the component. With the MenuItem code I can give you the answer on how to proceed/

Comment: sorry .  i copoied the wrong conde

Comment: import React from 'react'
import {WithRouter} from 'react'


const Menuitem= function(props){
    return(
        <div className='card' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.imageUrl})` }} >
            <div className='text-frame'> 
                 <h1 className='title'>{props.title}</h1>
                <p className='subtitle'>shop now</p>
            </div>
         </div>
    
    )
}

export default Menuitem

Comment: please check the code after edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two different approaches. Both of them will require an extra prop that will be the actual url you want to access when clicking the menu item.

Assuming you modify your section array to look like this:

```
[{title: 'Your title', imageUrl: 'your-image.jpg', linkUrl: '/hats'}]
```

And you modify your extract function to add the url value as a prop in the MenuItem component:

```
function extract(item){
 return(
  <Menuitem 
   title={item.title}  imageUrl={item.imageUrl} linkUrl={item.linkUrl} />
 )
}
```

You can do this
First one: Using a Link component from react router:

```
 import React from "react";
 import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
 const Menuitem= function(props){
   return(
    <Link to={props.linkUrl}>
    <div className='card' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.imageUrl})` 
     }} >
        <div className='text-frame'> 
             <h1 className='title'>{props.title}</h1>
            <p className='subtitle'>shop now</p>
        </div>
     </div>
     </Link>
   )
  }
```

Now you will have to add extra styling because that will add a regular a tag, but I like this approach because for example you can open the link in a new tab since it is a regular link.

2. Using the history prop.

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
   const Menuitem= function(props){
      const history = useHistory()
      const goToPage = () => history.push(props.linkUrl)

      return(
        <div className='card' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.imageUrl})` 
            }} onClick={goToPage} >
         <div className='text-frame'> 
             <h1 className='title'>{props.title}</h1>
            <p className='subtitle'>shop now</p>
         </div>
       </div>
      )
     }
   ```

This approach is a basic on click so if you press the component it will go to the selected page, this will work but keep in mind that event bubbling will be harder if you add more on clicks inside the menu item, so please be aware of that.

Comment: i tried the first one but when i click nothing happens

Comment: this message is from console 
index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `to` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.

Comment: I updated the answer, you need to add the prop as I mentioned above.

Comment: const sections = [
    {
      title: 'hats',
      imageUrl:'https://i.ibb.co/cvpntL1/hats.png',
      id: 1,
      linkUrl: 'shop/hats'
    },
    {
      title: 'jackets',
      imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/px2tCc3/jackets.png',
      id: 2,
      linkUrl: 'shop/jackets'
    },
    {
      title: 'sneakers',
      imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/0jqHpnp/sneakers.png',
      id: 3,
      linkUrl: 'shop/sneakers'
    },
so i wrote   <Link to={props.linkUrl}>  . isn't that right ?

Comment: Yesss that is right, use linkUrl instead the url, I just updated the code with those changes.

Comment: thanks. that worked but like you the style went away . but it works

Comment: Yes you can try to make some styles that remove the a default ones.

Comment: when i click hats i get blank page although  in App.js  i set component={Hatspage} and it is defined

Answer (score 0):

You should fire an event inside your MenuItem in order to redirect the user

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
const history = useHistory()
<img onClick={() => history.push('/hats')} />
```

Comment: do that for every  page?